# How to use SciBERT in the best manner?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, text-classification, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm trying to use BERT models to do text classification. As the text is about scientific texts, I intend to use the **SicBERT** pre-trained model: https://github.com/allenai/scibert

I have faced several limitations which I want to know if there is any solutions for them:

1. When I want to do tokenization and batching, it only allows me to use `max_length` of <=512. Is there any way to use more tokens. Doen't this limitation of 512 mean that I am actually not using all the text information during training? Any solution to use all the text?
2. I have tried to use this pretrained library with other models such as DeBERTa or RoBERTa. But it doesn't let me. I has only worked with BERT. Is there anyway I can do that?
3. I know this is a general question, but any suggestion that I can improve my fine tuning (from data to hyper parameter, etc)? Currently, I'm getting ~75% accuracy. Thanks

**Codes:**

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('allenai/scibert_scivocab_uncased')

encoded_data_train = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
    df_train.text.values, 
    add_special_tokens=True, 
    return_attention_mask=True, 
    padding=True,
    max_length=256
)

input_ids_train = encoded_data_train['input_ids']
attention_masks_train = encoded_data_train['attention_mask']
labels_train = torch.tensor(df_train.label.values)

dataset_train = TensorDataset(input_ids_train, attention_masks_train, labels_train)

dataloader_train = DataLoader(dataset_train, 
                              sampler=RandomSampler(dataset_train), 
                              batch_size=batch_size)

model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('allenai/scibert_scivocab_uncased',
                                                      num_labels=len(labels),
                                                      output_attentions=False,
                                                      output_hidden_states=False)

epochs = 1

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5, eps=1e-8)

scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer,
num_training_steps=len(dataloader_train)*epochs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I want to do tokenization and batching, it only allows me to use max_length of <=512. Is there any way to use more tokens. Doen't this limitation of 512 mean that I am actually not using all the text information during training? Any solution to use all the text?

Yes, you are not using the complete text. And this is one of the limitations of BERT and T5 models, which limit to using 512 and 1024 tokens resp. to the best of my knowledge.

I can suggest you to use `Longformer` or `Bigbird` or `Reformer` models, which can handle sequence lengths up to `16k`, `4096`, `64k` tokens respectively. These are really good for processing longer texts like scientific documents.

> I have tried to use this pretrained library with other models such as DeBERTa or RoBERTa. But it doesn't let me. I has only worked with BERT. Is there anyway I can do that?

`SciBERT` is actually a pre-trained BERT model.
See this [issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2902) for more details where they mention the feasibility of converting BERT to ROBERTa:

`Since you're working with a BERT model that was pre-trained, you unfortunately won't be able to change the tokenizer now from a WordPiece (BERT) to a Byte-level BPE (RoBERTa).`

> I know this is a general question, but any suggestion that I can
> improve my fine tuning (from data to hyper parameter, etc)? Currently,
> I'm getting ~79% accuracy.

I would first try to tune the most important hyperparameter `learning_rate`. I would then explore different values for hyperparameters of `AdamW` optimizer and `num_warmup_steps` hyperparamter of the scheduler.